# How to obtain the actual SNMPGet-able OID from the MIB file using Net-SNMP?

Tags: snmp, net-snmp

I noticed that in some cases, the actual OID has an extra .0 or .1 or .2 added to the MIB Name, however, this doesn't happen all the time.  Using the very common SysName example.  Net-SNMP's SNMPTranslate and MIB browsers will show the OID of SysName as ".1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5".

[image]
[image]

However, the actual SysName OID is ".1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0" as if I were to issue an SNMPGet on ".1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5", it will fail.

Is the OID SysName 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0 or 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5?

To add to the confusion, a trailing 0 or 1 isn't always required.

Answer (score 3):

Managed objects, in SNMP, are of two types : **scalar** objects and **tabular** objects.

A managed object that always has a single instance is called a scalar object. Tabular objects, on the other hand, have multiple instances, such as the rows of a table. For example, the **MIB II** *system* group has seven "leaf" variables under it. Each of these objects is a scalar object. For example, the value of *sysUpTime* is the duration of time since re-initialization of a system's network management software (SNMP agent), measured in hundredths of a second. **The OID of scalar objects ends with .0.**

```
Object Name:        sysUpTime
Object ID:      1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0
Object Syntax:      TimeTicks
Object Access:      read-only
Object Status:      mandatory
Object Description:  The time (in hundredths of a second) since the
             network management portion of the system was last
             re-initialized.
```

Tables in SNMP are two-dimensional objects defined as an ASN.1 type called SEQUENCE OF. Each element of the sequence is an entry (row) in the table, which itself is a sequence of scalar-valued objects. SNMP does not allow tables to be nested within tables.

For example, the MIB II *interfaces* group contains simply one tabular object, the *ifTable*, which contains one row for each of a network interfaces. Each row in the table is an instance of the object *ifEntry*. Each row contains instances of the scalar-valued leaf objects *IfIndex*, *ifDescr* etc. The leaf objects are called columnar objects since the instances of each such object constitute one column in the table. Although these objects have scalar-valued instances, they are not scalar objects because they can have multiple instances.